# Numpy fft result is unexpected

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I used `fft.fft(data)` and plotted that result I was expecting to the frequency that I gave in data.
I was expecting to see 50 hz but I got something strange.

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data=[]

for x in range(1000):
    data.append(m.sin(2*m.pi*50*0.001*x))


plt.plot(np.fft.fft(data)/len(data))

plt.show()
```

What should I do to see 50 Hz as result?

Thank you very much

Comment: fyi, you can make `data` without that loop by using `np.sin(2*np.pi*50*np.linspace(0,1,1000)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the x axis in your plot.

First, create the data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
data = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t)
```

Now, get the frequencies:

```
f = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data), t[1]-t[0]) # length of data, and dt
```

And plot the magnitude of the fft *vs* frequencies:

```
data_fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data)) / len(data)
plt.plot(f, data_fft)
```

[image: fft]

Comment: +1: I'm sure you know, but it's probably also a good idea to plot the magnitude, especially since the imaginary component is much larger than the real in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question for the DSP stack exchange (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

You are doing two things that are causing the odd result:

1. You are performing a complex to complex FFT on real data, so you will have your signal mirrored about the Nyquist frequency (Hermitian symmetry).
2. You are dividing and plotting the complex output, not the Fourier amplitudes or powers.(Matplotlib doesn't "get" complex numbers, so this comes out looking like garbage.)

try this instead:

```
plt.plot(abs(np.fft.rfft(data))/(len(data)/2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick replies I appreciate all answers but I tried plt.plot(abs(np.fft.rfft(data))/len(data)) as ebarr's solution. There is one question about that. Amplitude is 0.5 in graph I was expecting 1 ???

Comment: if you use `rfft` then you must multiply by `2`.